# How to use Wikipedia's Table of Clebsch–Gordan coefficients?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory

Wikipedia has a nice article [outlining Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients).

For example, to my understaning, this table tells us how to combine two particles, each having a maximum total angular momentum $1$ into one wavefunction with maximum angular momentum $2$:

[image]

Take the first column from the last table. It tells us, I believe:

$|2,0\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} |1,1\rangle |1,-1\rangle +\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|1,0\rangle|1,0\rangle+\sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} |1,-1\rangle|1,1\rangle$

How I interpret this:

The total angular momentum of a particle which arises from such a combination of wavefunctions of two other particles will have total angular quantum number 2 (so total angular momentum $\sqrt{j(j+1)\hbar^2}=\sqrt{2(2+1)\hbar^2}$), but $0$ around the $z$ axis (as $m_j$, what I understand to be the angular momentum around the $z$ axis, is $0$).

So the constituent particle's angular momentum is not aligned with each other, in fact they are antialigned enough so that the total z-directional angular momentum will be 0.

Is this interpretation of what's going on correct? My concern is that there are no tables for $m=-1,-2$. If my interpretation of the situation is correct, I see no reason why I couldn't produce a combined particle with these $m$ values, if I can do it for $m=0,1,2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia article says the following:

> For brevity, solutions with $M < 0$ and $j_1 < j_2$ are omitted. They may be calculated using the simple relations
> $$ \langle j_{1},j_{2};m_{1},m_{2}\mid j_{1},j_{2};J,M\rangle =(-1)^{J-j_{1}-j_{2}}\langle j_{1},j_{2};-m_{1},-m_{2}\mid j_{1},j_{2};J,-M\rangle .$$
> and
> $$ \langle j_{1},j_{2};m_{1},m_{2}\mid j_{1},j_{2};J,M\rangle =(-1)^{J-j_{1}-j_{2}}\langle j_{2},j_{1};m_{2},m_{1}\mid j_{2},j_{1};J,M\rangle.$$

In other words, the Clebsch-Gordon coefficients for a negative value of $m$ are the same (up to a sign) as those for the corresponding positive value of $m$, so long as you switch the signs of $m_1$ and $m_2$ as well.